# Runtime Error: 1004 : Save as method of worksheet class failed on MAC

Tags: excel, vba, macos

This is MAC specific issue, on WindowsOS, it works absolutely fine.

In this macro, I am fetching values from certain cells (from Sheet 1) & then copying this concatenated text to Sheet 3 of this spreadsheet.

While executing the code on MAC having Excel 2016, I am receiving the error

> RunTime Error 1004: SaveAs method of Worsheet class Failed.

Error code as below:
`Worksheets("Sheet3").SaveAs Filename:=path1 & "\" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(28, 2).Value & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False`

Complete code is as below:

```
Sub Generate()
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect ("laces")

Dim sOutputPath As String
Dim val2 As Variant
Dim lastrow As Long

path1 = ActiveWorkbook.Path

Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set Osheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

sVal1 = Osheet.Cells(37, 2).Value & Osheet.Cells(37, 3).Value & Osheet.Cells(37, 4).Value & ";" 'Reference Mapping
sVal1 = sVal1 & Osheet.Cells(2, 9).Value & ";" 'Date Mapping
sVal1 = sVal1 & Osheet.Cells(29, 2).Value & Osheet.Cells(29, 3).Value & Osheet.Cells(29, 4).Value & ";"  'Name Mapping
sVal1 = sVal1 & Osheet.Cells(28, 2).Value & Osheet.Cells(28, 3).Value & Osheet.Cells(28, 4).Value & ";"   'Company Mapping
sVal1 = sVal1 & Osheet.Cells(30, 2).Value & Osheet.Cells(30, 3).Value & Osheet.Cells(30, 4).Value & ";"   'Street1 Mapping
sVal1 = sVal1 & "a" & ";"    'Street2 Mapping
sVal1 = sVal1 & Osheet.Cells(31, 2).Value & Osheet.Cells(31, 3).Value & Osheet.Cells(31, 4).Value & ";"   'Zip Code Mapping
sVal1 = sVal1 & Osheet.Cells(32, 2).Value & Osheet.Cells(32, 3).Value & Osheet.Cells(32, 4).Value & ";"   'City Mapping
sVal1 = sVal1 & "" & ";"    'Region Mapping
sVal1 = sVal1 & Osheet.Cells(33, 2).Value & Osheet.Cells(33, 3).Value & Osheet.Cells(33, 4).Value & ";"   'Country Mapping
sVal1 = sVal1 & Osheet.Cells(34, 2).Value & Osheet.Cells(34, 3).Value & Osheet.Cells(34, 4).Value & ";"   'Email Mapping
sVal1 = sVal1 & Osheet.Cells(35, 2).Value & Osheet.Cells(35, 3).Value & Osheet.Cells(35, 4).Value & ";"   'Phone Mapping

hData1 = "Reference;Date;Name;Company;Street1;Street2;Zip Code;City;Region;Country;Email;Phone;Product;SKU;Quantity"

Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Value = hData1
hData1 = ""

'Product & Quality Mapping
For i = 6 To 13

 S = Osheet.Cells(i, 6).Value
 M = Osheet.Cells(i, 7).Value
 L = Osheet.Cells(i, 8).Value
 XL = Osheet.Cells(i, 9).Value

  If (S = "" And M = "" And L = "" And XL = "") Then

  Else

' SKU Mapping

SKU = Osheet.Cells(i, 1).Value & " - " & Osheet.Cells(i, 2).Value

If S <> "" Then
expKey = Osheet.Cells(i, 2).Value & "S"
sQuantity = Osheet.Cells(i, 6)


val3 = findSKU((Osheet.Cells(i, 2).Value), Left(Osheet.Cells(5, 6).Value, 1))
rData1 = sVal1 & sProduct & SKU & " " & Application.Trim(Osheet.Cells(5, 6).Value) & " / " & Osheet.Cells(i, 2).Value & ";" & val3 & ";" & sQuantity
val3 = ""

lRow = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1 + lRow, 1).Value = rData1


rData1 = ""
End If

If M <> "" Then
expKey = Osheet.Cells(i, 2).Value & "M"
sQuantity = Osheet.Cells(i, 7)
val4 = findSKU((Osheet.Cells(i, 2).Value), Left(Osheet.Cells(5, 7).Value, 1))
rData1 = sVal1 & sProduct & SKU & " " & Application.Trim(Osheet.Cells(5, 7).Value) & " / " & Osheet.Cells(i, 2).Value & ";" & val4 & ";" & sQuantity
val4 = ""
lRow = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1 + lRow, 1).Value = rData1
rData1 = ""
End If


If L <> "" Then
expKey = Osheet.Cells(i, 2).Value & "L"
sQuantity = Osheet.Cells(i, 8)
val3 = findSKU((Osheet.Cells(i, 2).Value), Left(Osheet.Cells(5, 8).Value, 1))
rData1 = sVal1 & sProduct & SKU & " " & Application.Trim(Osheet.Cells(5, 8).Value) & " / " & Osheet.Cells(i, 2).Value & ";" & val3 & ";" & sQuantity
val3 = ""
lRow = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1 + lRow, 1).Value = rData1

rData1 = ""
End If

If XL <> "" Then
expKey = Osheet.Cells(i, 2).Value & "XL"
sQuantity = Osheet.Cells(i, 9)
val3 = findSKU((Osheet.Cells(i, 2).Value), Left(Osheet.Cells(5, 9).Value, 2))
rData1 = sVal1 & sProduct & SKU & " " & Application.Trim(Osheet.Cells(5, 9).Value) & " / " & Osheet.Cells(i, 2).Value & ";" & val3 & ";" & sQuantity
val3 = ""
lRow = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1 + lRow, 1).Value = rData1

rData1 = ""
End If

End If

Next

Worksheets("Sheet3").SaveAs Filename:=path1 & "\" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(28, 2).Value & ".csv", _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False


MsgBox "You can find the generated  CSV file in " & path1

Sheet3.Cells.Clear

ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
Set oExcel = Nothing


ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect ("laces")
End Sub


Function findSKU(farb As String, size As String) As String

Dim ri As Long
    For ri = 2 To 33
        If Sheet2.Cells(ri, 1).Value = farb And Sheet2.Cells(ri, 2).Value = size Then
        findSKU = Sheet2.Cells(ri, 3).Value
        Exit Function
        End If

        Next ri

End Function
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Fairly sure you can only save a workbook, not a worksheet. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx

Comment: @SJR No! At least worksheets do have a `SaveAs` method. See  [Worksheet.SaveAs Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195820.aspx)

Comment: @Peh - I stand corrected.

Comment: What value is this `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(28, 2).Value`?

Comment: I don't know much about MacOS but I'm fairly sure it uses `/` as path separators and Windows uses `\ ` so this might be an issue. You can use `Application.PathSeparator` instead to see if it works.

Comment: @SJR , this is fetching the name of CSV from worksheet 1 column 28 B

Comment: @Peh ...Thanks for highlighting the issue, I have corrected this however same error is displayed.

Comment: Yes but what exactly is the name? Perhaps it's not a valid file name.

Comment: @SJR : The current value is "Zenfulfillment" in this cell

Comment: The code works well on Windows OS with this name. Earlier I was using FileSystemObject however this isn't supported on Mac